# How to print lastest commit time of every sub folder in git repo?

Tags: bash, git, shell

I know I can use `git log` with pretty log format `%ci` to get last commit time of any file.

```
git log -1 --pretty="format:%ci" /path/to/repo/anyfile.any
```

> -1 restricts it to the very last time the file changed

My encounter problem is that I want to clear long-term non-maintenance sub folder on a huge git repo.
According to last commit time, I can comfirm what folder should be cleared.

Furthermore, does anyway exist to print folder deepth only restricted to 1 level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find` with `-exec` option to ask git the last commit for each found directory:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -name .git -exec git log -n1 --format=format:"%ci {}" -- \{} \;
```

Comment: missing right bracket, to fix "Mismatched brackets".  

find -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -name .git -exec git log -n1 --format=format:"%ci {}" -- \{\} \;

Answer (score 0):

```
find /path/to/repo -maxdepth 1 -type d \! -name .git
```

Using command [`find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) list all objects with maximum depth 1, filter only directories (`-type d`) and exclude directory `.git` (`\!` means "not").

Answer (score 0):

```
git -C /path/to/repo ls-tree -d --name-only HEAD
```

Using [`git ls-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-tree) but that lists directories from `HEAD`, not from the file system.